# How can I add a scope to all ActiveRecord::Base classes by a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Im trying to add a scope to all ActiveRecord::Base subclasses but my approaches dont work because The classes need to be touched before they are listed by calling`ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses` or `ActiveRecord::Base.descendants`. So I cant extend the classes in a loop by including my ActiveSupport::Concern extended class which includes the scope.

Also I cant use `Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("app/models*.rb").to_s)` to list and require all the files. Because Rails.root returns `nil` until the environment is loaded.

So how can I extend all ActiveRecord::Base subclasses with my scope from a gem?

Answer (score 1):

Add to all subclasses exactly:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.instance_eval <<-EOV
      scope ...
    EOV
    super
  end
end
```

Add to ActiveRecord::Base

```
module MyScope
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    scope ...
  end
end

# Load it before_initialize:

class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
  config.before_initialize do
    ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
      include MyScope
    end
  end
end
```